# The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context error VS2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Getting an error The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context error in asp.net whenever I open a .cshtml file in my web project.

I should note that I got this solution fresh from our source repo and other developers tell me they don't see this issue.

Web project has a referenced to a nuget package and when I look at System.Web.MVC it's Mvc.4.0.40804

Things I've tried based on posted solutions:

1) Unloaded project and deleted .user file and did a clean and rebuilt. 
2) Deleted temp ASP files in the .net framework directory.

There are a lot of other solutions saying to move views or adding to web.config file, but if other developers using same solution aren't facing this - I'm thinking it's machine specific.

I don't see any reference errors in the web project.

When I installed VS2017, I just did the ASP.NET development.  So, i have no gotten another version of MVC.  Could it be that?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up modifying my VS2017 install and under ASP.NET and web development, I uninstalled that and reinstalled and made sure ASP.NET MVC 4 was checked off under Optional.